# How can I terminate the console?

Tags: c++, math, switch-statement, terminate

a newbie here. I have the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int choice;
    double radius, length, width, base, height;
    const double PI = 3.14159;

    cout << ":Geometry Calculator:\n\n";
    cout << "1. Calculate the Area of a Circle \n";
    cout << "2. Calculate the Area of a Rectangle \n";
    cout << "3. Calculate the Area of a Triangle \n";
    cout << "4. Quit\n";
    cout << "4. Please pick number: " ;
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        double aCirc;
        cout << "Enter the RADIUS of your Circle: ";
        cin >> radius;
        aCirc = PI * pow(radius, 2);
        cout << "The AREA of your CIRCLE IS: " << aCirc;
        break;
    case 2:
        double aRec;
        cout << "Enter the LENGTH and WIDTH of your Rectangle (seprate your numbers with a space): ";
        cin >> length >> width;
        aRec = length * width;
        cout << "The AREA of your Rectangle is: " << aRec;
        break;
    case 3:
        double aTri;
        cout << "Enter the BASE and HEIGHT of your Triangle (separate your numbers with a space): ";
        cin >> base >> height;
        aTri = (base * height) / 2;
        break;
    case 4:
        exit();
    default:
        cout << "\n You entered an Invalid Number GoodBye No Number" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to terminate the console without immediately after the user presses "4" I searched different possible functions however I believe I'm utilizing them incorrectly, I thought this was correct, I saw it in another site however it did not work, Can anyone help?? Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Do you mean, when the user press "4" the program terminates, not when the user press "4" and "Return"?

Comment: yes that's right, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking calling `exit()` is a bad practice because if your application contain larger code it gives you unexpected behaviour when trying to debug and understand why your application suddenly vanished into thin air (assuming you do not remember all your code by heart).
In your sample here I think calling `break` and issueing a log statement would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getch()` of `conio.h`. it will return a character that you can convert to the equivalent number. getch() blocks the program until you press a key. Also as @PazO says, don't use `exit`